# Check if a node has objects - javafx

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

Here's the algorithm I am working on:

```
If (MouseEvent) { 
    Handle the mouse event { 
       if (Node rect == null) {
           rect.getChildren.remove(circles.getChildren())
       }  
    } 
}
```

I got stuck at checking if a Node has objects, is there a method for this?

Comment: Instead of checking whether a node has children, you are declaring a node `rect` and assigning it to null. A more detailed question will help answering your query, as in, on which node are you applying the `mouseEvent` and where on which node do you need to do operation on !

Comment: @ItachiUchiha - The mouse event is on the rectangle node. I want to clear everything on the node. How can I do it?

rect.addEventHandler(......{handle(Check if node has objects) {}})

I am stuck at check if node has objects on it, if it does, then clear it.

Comment: @Pgram, how are you adding circles to the rectangle? How are you establishing the relation between them?

Comment: @UlukBiy 


Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100);
rect.addEventHandler(.....handle ()
{if (rect node has circle) clear it}

Circle circle = new circle(,,)
rect.getChildren().add(circle);
}


My question is about, how to check if a node has objects and how to clear the objects pertaining to that node.

Comment: @Pgram Please edit your question, instead of writing codes in the comment !

Comment: @Pgram Rectangle has not a getChildren() method!

Comment: @UlukBiy, yes you are right, I have no clue how I can go about doing this... :(

Comment: @Pgram, then re-express your question by editing it. You should to "add" first before trying to "remove" somethings :).